# Is there a Python headless browser suitable for Behave without using Selenium or a real browser

Tags: python, django, bdd, python-behave

I've a history in the PHP/Symfony world, so I am familiar with using Behat (like Behave) without having to use a full Selenium setup. To achieve this they use a [GoutteDriver](http://mink.behat.org/en/latest/drivers/goutte.html) (written in PHP) instead of driving a real web browser like Chrome or Firefox.

Is it possible to do something similar in Python (specifically, Django) with Behave?

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed possible - you can use [Splinter](https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). As well as allowing you to drive Chrome or Firefox, it also has drivers that work in the way you describe. For Django, there's a [Django driver](https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/drivers/django.html).